# Generic hierarchy filter of nested classes in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing an Application that contains a nested structure like this one:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<State> States { get; set; } = new();
}

public class State
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
}

public class Shop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Area { get; set; }
}
```

with the mock data:

```
private static List<Country> GenerateData()
    {
        List<Country> countries = new();
        
        Country country =  new()
        {
            Name = "USA", 
            States = new List<State>()
            {
                new State()
                {
                    Name = "Texas",
                    Cities = new List<City>()
                    {
                        new City()
                        {
                            Name = "Dallas",
                            Shops = new List<Shop>()
                            {
                                new Shop()
                                {
                                    Name = "Walmart",
                                    Area = 30000
                                },
                                new Shop()
                                {
                                    Name = "Walmart",
                                    Area = 40000
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new City()
                        {
                            Name = "Austin",
                            Shops = new List<Shop>()
                            {
                                new Shop()
                                {
                                    Name = "Walmart",
                                    Area = 20000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new State()
                {
                    Name = "Alabama",
                    Cities = new List<City>()
                    {
                        new City()
                        {
                            Name = "Auburn",
                            Shops = new List<Shop>()
                            {
                                new Shop()
                                {
                                    Name = "MyShop",
                                    Area = 500
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new City()
                        {
                            Name = "Dothan",
                            Shops = new List<Shop>()
                            {
                                new Shop()
                                {
                                    Name = "MyShop2",
                                    Area = 6000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
                
        };
        
        countries.Add(country);

        return countries;
    }
```

My goal is to filter this nested structure like this:

Search for City name containing **"Dal"**. Result shall be the full hierarchy from the root down to the shops. In that case:

```
- USA
 - Texas
  - Dallas
   - Walmart (Area: 30000)
   - Walmart (Area: 40000)
```

Another filter might be filtering the shop name, e.g. search for **"MyShop2"** would result in:

```
- USA
 - Alabama
  - Dothan
   - MyShop2 (Area: 6000)
```

I'm somewhat familiar with linq, so filtering for the city's name can look like:

```
var result =
    from country in countries
    from state in country.States
    from city in state.Cities
    where city.Name.Contains("Dal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    select city;
```

But in that case, I'll get the city and shops only. How to the get hierarchy (country and state) at the top in the result?

Same is for the second search:

```
 var result =
     from country in countries
     from state in country.States
     from city in state.Cities
     from shop in city.Shops
     where shop.Name.Contains(nameFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     select shop;
```

Here I'll get only the shop without the hierarchy above...

Comment: You want to return a copy of country that contains only the matched results?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Basically "keeping the path".

Comment: Is this going to be leveraging Entity Framework or should this be a pure Linq solution computing everything in memory?

Comment: No, an Entity Framework is not involved. It must not be a pure Linq solution...

Comment: @Maverick007 What .NET version are you using?

Comment: @V0ldek .NET 6.0

Comment: _"It must not be a pure Linq solution."_ What do you mean by this? What should it be then? The question Marco asked related to the notion that in-memory LINQ is a bit less constrained than when it is used in conjuction with an ORM (EF or other). In-memory, you're much more able to reference and reuse logic, which doesn't always translate well when an ORM is involved.

Comment: @Flater Well, it can be a combination of for/foreach loops instead. But my first thought was that a Linq solution would be the way to go, as Ortiga has been shown.

Comment: @Maverick007: We're dealing with a mistranslation then. "Must not be" means "is not allowed to be". What you intended to say if that it "doesn't have to be" a pure linq solution.

Comment: @Flater. Yes, you're right... Sorry for the mistranslation from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to select the whole hierarchy, you need to group the results by your topmost node, i.e., country, and rebuild from there

```
var result =
    from country in countries
    from state in country.States
    from city in state.Cities
    from shop in city.Shops
    where shop.Name.Contains(nameFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    select new { country, state, city, shop } into p
    group p by p.country into g
    let shops = g.Select(x => x.shop)
    let cities = g.Select(x => x.city).Distinct()
    let states = g.Select(x => x.state).Distinct()
    select new Country()
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        States = states.Select(s => new State()
        {
            Name = s.Name,
            Cities = s.Cities.Intersect(cities).Select(c => new City()
            {
                Name = c.Name,
                Shops = c.Shops.Intersect(shops).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. That'll do it. Any ideas how to write the where clause dependent on the type? So, basically there will be 4 different where clauses, e.g.: where x.Name.Contains("Dal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase). Where x is one of country, state, city and shop?

Comment: Are they different optional terms, e.g., you get 4 strings one for each of country, state, city and shop? Or a single term that should search any of them?

Comment: The latter one.

Answer (score 0):

You have the relevant path in a sense in the queries you've shown

```
var result =
    from country in countries
    from state in country.States
    from city in state.Cities
    where city.Name.Contains("Dal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    select (country, state, city);
```

This will select triples that specify a path to a given city. Now you want to take such triples and turn them into your class structure, so, well, we do just that. Define a `Path` class:

```cs
class FilteredPath
{
    public Country? Country { get; init; }

    public State? State { get; init; }

    public City? City { get; init; }

    public Shop? Shop { get; init; }
}
```

And then we write lots of code:

```cs
class FilteredBuilder
{
    private List<Country> _countries = new();

    public FilteredBuilder AddPath(FilteredPath path)
    {
        if (path.Country is null)
        {
            return this;
        }

        if (path.State is null)
        {
            AddFullCountry(path.Country);
        }
        else
        {
            Country country = GetOrCreateBy(_countries, c => c.Name == path.Country.Name);
            country.Name = path.Country.Name;

            AddPathTo(country, path);
        }

        return this;
    }

    private void AddFullCountry(Country country)
    {
        _countries.RemoveAll(c => c.Name == country.Name);
        _countries.Add(country);
    }
    private void AddFullState(Country country, State state)
    {
        country.States.RemoveAll(s => s.Name == state.Name);
        country.States.Add(state);
    }

    private void AddFullCity(State state, City city)
    {
        state.Cities.RemoveAll(c => c.Name == city.Name);
        state.Cities.Add(city);
    }

    private void AddFullShop(City city, Shop shop)
    {
        city.Shops.RemoveAll(s => s.Name == shop.Name && s.Area == shop.Area);
        city.Shops.Add(shop);
    }

    private void AddPathTo(Country country, FilteredPath path)
    {
        Debug.Assert(path.State is not null);
        if (path.City is null)
        {
            AddFullState(country, path.State);
        }
        else
        {
            State state = GetOrCreateBy(country.States, s => s.Name == path.State.Name);
            state.Name = path.State.Name;

            AddPathTo(state, path);
        }
    }

    private void AddPathTo(State state, FilteredPath path)
    {
        Debug.Assert(path.City is not null);
        if (path.Shop is null)
        {
            AddFullCity(state, path.City);
        }
        else
        {
            City city = GetOrCreateBy(state.Cities, s => s.Name == path.City.Name);
            city.Name = path.City.Name;

            AddPathTo(city, path);
        }
    }

    private void AddPathTo(City city, FilteredPath path)
    {
        Debug.Assert(path.Shop is not null);
        AddFullShop(city, path.Shop);
    }

    private static T GetOrCreateBy<T>(ICollection<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : new()
    {
        T? result = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        if (result is null)
        {
            result = new T();
            source.Add(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
        
    public List<Country> Build()
    {
        var result = _countries;
        _countries = new();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Fire it up like this:

```
var result =
    from country in countries
    from state in country.States
    from city in state.Cities
    where city.Name.Contains("Dal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    select (country, state, city);

var paths = result.Select(r => new FilteredPath
{
    Country = r.country,
    State = r.state,
    City = r.city
});

var builder = new FilteredBuilder();

foreach (var path in paths)
{
    builder.AddPath(path);
}

var filtered = builder.Build();
```

There a few considerations to take if you want this in production:

1. Looking up `List`s is inefficient. You probably want a helper type for each entity that will have a `Dictionary` to lookup their children by name, and then convert to your original model at the end.
2. There surely is a way to make this more generic and avoid code repetition, but, to quote a classic, "I didn't have time to make it short".

However it does generalize to different types of queries. You're filtering states? Just pass `null` to both `City` and `Shop` of the `FilteredPath`.

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IHIOZk